# Передать параметр в метод value() Xml data type method

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день

Есть XML

```
<income date="10-10-2003T00:00:00" storageId="1" currencyId="2" organizationId="123">
    <goods num="1" stringNum="1" id="5" count="1" price="10" sum="10"/>
    <goods num="1" stringNum="1" id="6" count="2" price="10" sum="20"/>
    <goods num="1" stringNum="1" id="7" count="3" price="10" sum="30"/>
</income>
```

Хранимая процедура TRANSACT-SQL должна парсить теги этого XML.

Не могу передать в метод value параметр вместо захардкоженного числа (1).

```
select @XML.value('(/income/goods/@price)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
```

Пробую так:

```
declare @x INT = 1
select @XML.value('(/income/goods/@price)[@x]', 'nvarchar(max)');
// ошибка: There is no attribute named '@x' in the type 
// 'attribute(price,xdt:untypedAtomic)'

select @XML.value('(/income/goods/@price)['+@x+']', 'nvarchar(max)');
// ошибка: The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a 
// string literal.
```

Возможно вообще так сделать? В гугле не нашёл пример

Comment: но это же просто строка, переменные в ней я так понимаю не интерполируются (не подставляются), соберите строку из частей, что то вроде `'(/income/goods/@price)[' + cast(@x as varchar) + ']'`  (только посмотрите действительно ли в sql-server строки объединяются знаком `+` и в cast приведение типа возможно чуть по другому). Дочитал вопрос до конца :) Думаю cast вам поможет

Answer (score 1):

Метод `value` может принимать в качестве XPath аргумента только строковые литералы. Использование выражений не разрешается (второе сообщение об ошибке как раз об этом и говорит). Внутри XPath, однако, можно ссылаться на sql-переменные с помощью функции `sql:variable`.

Если нужно получить значение атрибута *price* у элемента *goods*, который является `@x`-ым по счёту в *income*, то это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
declare @x int = 1;
select
    @XML.value('(/income/goods[position()=sql:variable("@x")]/@price)[1]', 'decimal(12,3)');
```

Или, например, по *id*:

```
declare @goodsId int = 6;
select
    @XML.value('(/income/goods[@id=sql:variable("@goodsId")]/@price)[1]', 'decimal(12,3)');
```